# to determine the controller, action , route name in zend framework3 in module.php

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I trying to get the matched route name and controller - action name, in ZF3
I want this in Module.php,

as i have tried-

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
   $app = $e->getApplication();
    $em  = $app->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();

    $routeMatch = $sm->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
   }
```

but it returns `null`,

Thanks in advance

Comment: On bootstrap (function onBootstrap), the route is not yet prepared, so you need to get route on some event, for Ex:(EVENT_DISPATCH, EVENT_RENDER, EVENT_ROUTE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this-

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
        {

            $app = $e->getApplication();
            $em  = $app->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
            $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();
    $app->getEventManager()->attach( MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function ($e) use ($sm){
                $routeMatch = $sm->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();
                var_dump($routeMatch->getParams());
                var_dump($routeMatch->getMatchedRouteName());exit;
            }, 200);
    }
```

On bootstrap (function onBootstrap), the route is not yet prepared, so you need to get route on some events,

for Ex:(EVENT_DISPATCH, EVENT_RENDER, EVENT_ROUTE)